# Bug in webkit? Mouse move events fire continuously when windows media player is running

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit, windows-media-player, onmousemove

In Safari & Chrome (not in FireFox, e.g. "in webkit"), when we're playing Windows Media Player in the background and we listen for mouse move events (using JQuery here), we're seeing mouse move events fire even when the mouse isn't moving.

This **only** happens when windows media player is running, and stops occurring if the mouse moves outside of the canvas.

But if the user leaves the computer with the music playing and the mouse in the canvas, we can't identify their idle state.

Questions:

- Anyone heard of this? Gotta magic fix?
- This seems like a webkit issue, but I'm no webkit expert, how would I go about announcing it to the webkit folks?

Comment: [Webkit Bug Tracker](https://bugs.webkit.org/enter_bug.cgi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that could be one of Windows Media's approaches to avoiding idle state when playing... from what I've read online - in several locations - with regards to C/C++ coders asking about avoiding idle state, this comes up as a solution *(No idea if it is good solution or not, it seems to be a fix for problems in XP)*.

e.g.

[Trying to disable Processor idle states (C states) on Windows PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721218/trying-to-disable-processor-idle-states-c-states-on-windows-pc)

It could be that FireFox also checks for changes in mouse position rather than just a trigger of the event... whereas WebKit does not. Just a wild guess anyways. To fix maybe you could do the same... listen for a change in `event.screenX`, `event.screenY` rather than just the event firing?